# Realm database callbacks

Tags: swift, realm

I'm looking at implementing callbacks for some objects in my code. So far the object I have is the following:

```
class Contact: Object {
    @objc dynamic var uid: String? = nil
    @objc dynamic var fullName: String? = nil
    @objc dynamic var givenName: String? = nil
    @objc dynamic var familyName: String? = nil
}
```

Ideally, I would like to fill `fullName` once `givenName` and `familyName` have a value.

I noticed that Realm has events, but they seem to be pretty broad and I'm not sure that implementing such mechanism will not create more issues than good in my app as I only need to trigger it when the Contact object is being manipulated.

Any suggestion or best practice to share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for are computed properties. However, Realm currently doesn't support storing computed properties, but you don't really need to persist `fullName` in Realm, since as long as `givenName` and `familyName` are persisted, you can always compute `fullName`.

```
class Contact: Object {
    @objc dynamic var uid: String? = nil
    @objc dynamic var givenName: String? = nil
    @objc dynamic var familyName: String? = nil
    var fullName: String? {
        if let givenName = givenName, let familyName = familyName {
            return "\(givenName) \(familyName)"
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually what I'm currently doing. However, I would have found interesting to have a way to use "Computed properties" as there are other cases where it's not so trivial.